# (GOOGLE SHEETS)How do I reference a 'named range' data argument of my QUERY FUNCTION to another cell?

Tags: sql, google-sheets, named-ranges

GOOGLE SHEETS

The user will just have to type the **named range** on the *greyed cell* without having to modify the query function.

[QUERY SHEET//](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gt3RS.png)
[FRUIT TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkuZl.png)

Comment: See my addendum below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `INDIRECT`, i.e.:

`=QUERY(INDIRECT(A3),"Select *")`

I assume you'll be adding more to the `Select` clause. Otherwise (i.e. if you are wanting to pull the whole range without conditions), you can just use the `INDIRECT` function alone:

`=INDIRECT(A3)`